# Converting spaces in a text file to periods/full stops

Tags: text-processing, files, text, text-formatting

I'm quite new to Linux so forgive my ignorance.

I have a regular text file with plain text. I would like to know if it's possible to convert all the spaces within the file to periods/full stops.

For example,
"The rain is relentless" to "The.rain.is.relentless"

The text file is quite large so it would be remiss of me not to put it to the forum.

Thanks very much.

Comment: could be there multiple spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
sed -i 'y/ /./' file
```

With '-i' the file is overwritten with the new replacements. Without '-i' the file is not changed, the replacements are printed to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Many tools can do that, e.g. `sed`:

```
sed 's/ /./g' file
```

or `tr`:

```
tr ' ' . <file
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed did work. Although didn't overwrite - as seshoumara mentioned below I needed the -i.